# Dataframe unable to correctly set index for matplotlib use

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

For the following

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
#%matplotlib inline 
sorted(df.columns)
df = df[df.region=="US"]
df.set_index('date')
df.head(50)
def plot_cat(df_input, cat, color="green"):
    axis = df_input[cat].plot(figsize=(10,6), color=color, fontsize=10, zorder=2)
    axis.set_xlabel("date", fontsize=font_size)
    axis.set_ylabel("", fontsize=font_size); 
    axis.axhline(y=0)
plot_cat(df, "retail", "red")
```

Using the following data
https://pastebin.pl/view/b7f35915

The resulting graph does not use "date" for the x-axis.

Though I set index to be date it does not appear to do this. The output from df.head(50) above is as such:

```
    region  date    retail
0   US  2020-02-15  5.0
1   US  2020-02-16  8.0
2   US  2020-02-17  5.0
3   US  2020-02-18  0.0
4   US  2020-02-19  3.0
5   US  2020-02-20  1.0
6   US  2020-02-21  3.0
7   US  2020-02-22  9.0
8   US  2020-02-23  6.0
9   US  2020-02-24  3.0
10  US  2020-02-25  4.0
11  US  2020-02-26  8.0
12  US  2020-02-27  9.0
13  US  2020-02-28  10.0
14  US  2020-02-29  12.0
```

I am not sure why this isn't being set as the index, and I believe this to be the reason why the matplot graph fails to have the correct x-axis.

There are no warning messages or errors at any stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@gtomer's answer should solve your problem. Another option without changing your data is pass `x` to `plot`:

```
def plot_cat(df_input, cat, color="green"):
    # change here
    axis = df_input.plot(x='date', y=cat,
                         figsize=(10,6), color=color, 
                         fontsize=10, zorder=2)

    axis.set_xlabel("date", fontsize=font_size)
    axis.set_ylabel("", fontsize=font_size); 
    axis.axhline(y=0)

plot_cat(df, 'retail', 'red')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Okay when I do that nothing seems to change. 

Unfortunately when I change the code to df = df.set_index('date') I get the error message "float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Period'"

Comment: Please check your code a gain. I updated the answer with output of my code with sample data.

Answer (score 1):

Change the set_index row to:

```
df = df.set_index('date')
```

or:

```
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
```